React Pdf don't show image
I use the React PDF Image library component and pass an image into it as shown in the documentation and tutorials on YouTube, but the image is not displayed, what could be the problem? To check the pictures I used a standard tag and everything will be displayed.
import ReactPDF, { Canvas, Document, Page, StyleSheet, Text, Image, View } from '@react-pdf/renderer'
import { Stage, Layer, Group, Rect } from "react-konva";
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import imgNew from '../../images/Drawer.png'


function PdfFile(props) {

   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      body: {},
      title: {},
      image: {}
   })



   return (


      <div>

         <Document>
            <Page style={styles.body}>

               <Text style={styles.title}>
                  Hello world
               </Text>
               <View style={styles.image}>

                  <Image style={styles.image} src={imgNew} />
                  <Image style={styles.image} src={`${imgNew}/>`} />
                   <Image style={styles.image} src={`data:image/png;base64,${imgNew} `} />
               <Image style={styles.image} src='/images/Drawer.png' />
               </View>


            </Page>


         </Document>
         {/* <img src={imgNew} /> */}
      </div>





   )
}

export default PdfFile

I tried passing the image as a path, but it still wasn't displayed.
I tried adding /> React-pdf show image from base64 data string
but didn't work
The problem is that in the DOM, links to images look normal.


@KJ,My picture will always come as a variable.  And I’m just using this as an example to check how to insert a picture.

@KJ,I checked the image through the standard Img tag and the image shows the problem is in the React PDF tag

@KJ,standard IMG tag, if you insert the path to the image or data:image/png;base64 into it, then everything is shown. And the component for displaying pictures that @react-pdf/renderer provides, it does not display a single picture. I did it as shown in the documentation, but it doesn’t work.

@KJ, You are right, you understand, the tag seems to have been written as in the documentation. Maybe try running it yourself. I do everything this way: initially, a picture made from Canvas is transferred to this component, and it didn’t work, and now I’m checking it with a regular picture to understand how it works.

@KJ,I don’t understand about capital letters, I already use capital letters, in the code above I use the standard Image component, or we misunderstood each other, please show your code.

@KJ,So in the code above I use  and it doesn’t work.

@KJ, As I understand it, image is a standard html element, and when launched, it itself changes to image instead of Image.
